# Removing object from mongoose query results but extra objects being removed

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following array of objects that I am getting from a mongoose find query:

```
  let exhibitions = [
        {
          "_id": "63047848edbb342f6805166e",
          "name":"Exhibition1"         
          "artworks": [
              {
                "_id": "6303519929e74916708b508b",             
                "instances": [
                    {
                      "_id": "630486e2a13932fa8e2ff4b5",
                      "parentID": "6303519929e74916708b508b",
                      "exhibitionID": "63047848edbb342f6805166e",
                      "HangLineID": "555",
                    },
                    {
                      "_id": "630486e2a13932fa8e2ff4b5",
                      "parentID": "6303519929e74916708b508b",
                      "exhibitionID": "63047848edbb342f6805166e",
                      "HangLineID": "444",
                    },
                ]
              },
              {
               "_id": "6304878ba13932fa8e2ff4d9",
                "instances": [
                    {
                      "_id": "6308377d7c60564627494e16",
                      "parentID": "6304878ba13932fa8e2ff4d9",
                      "exhibitionID": "6304dbfb2af05390425969f7",
                      "HangLineID": "333",
                    }
                ]           
              },               
          ],         
        },
        {          
          "_id": "6304dbfb2af05390425969f7", 
          "name":"Exhibition2"         
          "artworks": [
              {
                "_id": "62f20e22dc17b1712596016a",                  
                "instances": [
                    {
                      "_id": "6304dc672af0539042596a07",
                      "parentID": "62f20e22dc17b1712596016a",
                      "exhibitionID": "6304dbfb2af05390425969f7",
                      "HangLineID": "000",
                      "HangLineArtworkArrayPosition": 2,
                      "__v": 0
                    }
                ]
              }
        }
    ]
```

I have 2 exhibitions, each one with a different id, and inside each I have an "artworks" array of objects that includes an "instances" array of objects.
What I am trying to do is to remove the "instances" array elements for which instances.exhibitionID is different from exhibition._id.

Both instances.exhibitionID and exhibition._id are objects.

I have tried using splice and lodash and what is happening with my code is that I can get

```
{
  "_id": "6308377d7c60564627494e16",
  "parentID": "6304878ba13932fa8e2ff4d9",
  "exhibitionID": "6304dbfb2af05390425969f7",
  "HangLineID": "333",
}
```

removed from Exhibition1 but the code is also removing

```
{
  "_id": "6308377d7c60564627494e16",
  "parentID": "6304878ba13932fa8e2ff4d9",
  "exhibitionID": "6304dbfb2af05390425969f7",
  "HangLineID": "333",
}
```

from Exhibition2, where it rightfully belongs.

Here is my code:

```
exhibitions.map((exh, key)=>{ 
  const artworks = exh.artworks;
  artworks.map((artwork,index1) =>{
    const instances = artwork.instances
    _.remove(
      instances, 
      v => (
        v.exhibitionID.toString()!=(exh._id).toString())            
      )})
      
    })
```

I have tested the `v.exhibitionID.toString()!==(exh._id).toString()` condition in the loop with console.log and it returns the right values.
Also, when I do

```
  v => (
    v.HangLineID!="555"
  )})
```

it deletes and leaves the right elements. Does this mean my object comparison is wrong?

Comment: Perhaps this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ANenuG7A_eW) may helps in MongoDB query way.

Comment: the thing is that I get this results from a .find() query and popuplate, so I cannot access the exhitibion._id while doing the query